# running Project Wycheproof against crypto implementations in languages other than Java

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, test-vectors

So I guess https://github.com/google/wycheproof "*tests crypto libraries against known attacks*". It appears to mainly be intended for Java crypto providers but can it easily be adapted to be used for other languages?

For non timing attacks you could probably just loop through the *.json files in the testvectors directory but it's not clear to me what some of the data in there means.

Consider [ecdh_secp256r1.json](https://github.com/google/wycheproof/blob/master/testvectors/ecdh_secp256r1_test.json). Each test has a `shared` attribute and a `result` attribute. There appear to be 3x `shared` attributes: `valid`, `invalid` and `acceptable`. From the names I'd guess `valid` means that the library should produce the same result as the `shared` attribute. For `acceptable` I guess it means that, per the specs, it could either error out or return the same result as the `shared` attribute. For `invalid` I assume it should error out. BUT if that's what `invalid` means then why is there any data in the `shared` attribute at all?